# Find all real values of $a$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sin(\pi\sqrt{a^2+n^2})$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

To find all $a$ that makes the series diverge, it is sufficient to make the limit of $\sin(\pi\sqrt{a^2+n^2})$ not exist or exists but not  equal to $0$ as $n\to\infty.$
I suspect only $a=0$ would converge the series, and the limit of $\sin(\pi\sqrt{a^2+n^2})$ would not even exist if $a\neq 0.$ .

Comment: Let me guess: $|a| < \sqrt \frac{2}{\pi}$

Comment: Wrong guess. See my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

Observe that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sin(\pi\sqrt{a^2+n^2})&=\sin\left(n\pi\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{n^2}}\right)\\\\
&=\sin\left(n\pi+\frac{a^2\pi}{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)\\\\
&=(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{a^2\pi}{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?  Is there any real value for $a$ for which this series diverges?

Comment: Mine looked like yours and was too lengthy for nothing. I have deleted it! (+1)

Comment: Nice hint,$\,\,$ +1

Comment: @zhw.  Thank you my friend.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Starting like Mark Viola  we have to consider the sum

$$s = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \cos (\pi  n) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  a^2}{2 n}\right)$$

Now, expanding the $\sin()$ and exchanging the order of the summation gives under the k-sum:

$$\frac{(-1)^k \left(\frac{\pi  a^2}{2}\right)^{2 k+1} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{2 k+1} \cos (\pi  n)}{(2 k+1)!}$$

Doing the n-sum gives for the k-sum:

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{k+1} 2^{-4 k-1} \left(2^{2 k}-1\right) \pi ^{2 k+1} \left(a^2\right)^{2 k+1} \zeta (2 k+1)}{(2 k+1)!}$$

Doing the k-sum, neglecting the difference betwenn $\zeta$ and unity leads to

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{k+1} 2^{-4 k-1} \left(2^{2 k}-1\right) \pi ^{2 k+1} \left(a^2\right)^{2 k+1}}{(2 k+1)!} $$

which is explicitly

$$2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi  a^2}{4}\right)-\sin \left(\frac{\pi  a^2}{2}\right)$$

Hence, contrary to the "guess" in my comment there is no restrictin on "a" for convergence.

Comment: "... neglecting the difference between $\zeta$ and unity leads to "  Why have you bothered to carry out the inner sum only to neglect the factor $\zeta(2k+1)$ in the sum over $k$?  That makes little sense.  And one needs only use $\sin(x)=x+O(x^3)$ to show convergence.